# How can I read the app version defined in the manifest file programmatically?

Tags: android

In the Android manifest file, there is a field that specifies the application version.

How I can read that value programmatically?

Answer (score 36):

You can get access to that information through the `PackageInfo` class:

```
PackageInfo pinfo = this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
Log.d("pinfoCode",pinfo.versionCode);
Log.d("pinfoName",pinfo.versionName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `GetApplicationContext().PackageManager().getPackageInfo()`.  The `PackageInfo` object it returns will have what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    final String packageName = context.getPackageName();
    PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
    final int iconid = packageInfo.applicationInfo.icon; // for example

    // etc
} catch (android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {}
```